# Modernizr.js is firing twice

Tags: jquery, modernizr, octobercms, october-partial

I'm kinda new at this but I don't know why .js file appears to be firing twice on the front-end.

Note: I'm developing using the OctoberCMS platform

Here a share of my layout template code:

[image: Layout]

Comment: It would be better to include relevant parts of your code copy-pasted as text here (you can format it as "code" by indenting every line with four spaces) than to include it as an image. That way, others can easier refer to it by copy-pasting again, etc. instead of having to zoom into this big image file and type stuff out from it.

Comment: From the layout template that you posted I can see no obvious reason why modernizr. should load twice.
You could also tell us more exactly what is happening that makes you conclude that modernizr has loaded twice, or which function exactly is firing twice. Be more specific and descriptive what exactly is happening, what you are seeing and what you base your conclusions on.

Comment: I think these may be reasons why your question got downvoted. Be more specific and show us what you did to come to your conclusion.